# List a as a value in a map collected from stream

Tags: java, java-stream

i'm trying to modify source code from http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/ from *Advanced Operations* section to get a result type `Map<Integer, List<String>>` instead of `Map<Integer, String>` where value is concatenated string of multiple values.

```
    List<Person> persons =
            Arrays.asList(
                    new Person("Max", 18),
                    new Person("Peter", 23),
                    new Person("Pamela", 23),
                    new Person("David", 12)
            );

    Map<Integer, String> collect = persons.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.age, p -> Arrays.asList(p -> p.name)));
```

Error I get is:

> Error:(32, 25) java: incompatible types: inference variable U has incompatible bound 
>   equality constraints: java.lang.String 
>   lower bounds: java.util.List

How do I make it work?

Comment: If you want a Map<Integer, List<String>>, don't declare your variable with the type Map<Integer, String>. But toMap() won't do what you want. You want groupingBy(). Read the javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.mapping`

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> result = persons.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.age,
                    Collectors.mapping(p -> p.name, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Method references are generally considered as a better alternative to lambda since it is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so,

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> namesByAge = persons.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge, Collectors.mapping(Person::getName, Collectors.toList())));
```

You have to first group the People based on their age, then get the names of the people with that age and finally collect it using a downstream collector.

Comment: The OP wants a Map<Integer, List<String>>.